# Using Vue or React in Amazon MTurk's HTMLQuestion

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, mechanicalturk

I want to create an MTurk HTML question that uses a modern web framework, such as Vue or React. For a minute let's assume I can't use an ExternalQuestion which just points to a website I create, but rather want to use HTMLQuestion.

Is that doable? Can I include React, for example, and it will work? Amazon's surrounding HTML will not interfere with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Both [HTMLQuestion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HTMLQuestionArticle.html) and [ExternalQuestion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html) are rendered in an iframe when a worker accepts your HIT. As such, they're completely isolated from any other scripts or libraries on the surrounding page.